# Facebook app throws error "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

So I added a like box to my canvas application, but ever since keep getting the following error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match
>   the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of
>   one of the App's domains.

I've read through most questions asked on this topic, nearly all of them tell me to set my domain in the application settings, set up the page tab URL, enable Embedded browser OAuth Login, add a website platform with the domain URL - I've done all that, but to no avail. I'm not running the app on localhost, all the URLs entered coincide with the actual application URL. Yet I still keep getting this error, resulting in the like box appearing and disappearing randomly during different sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect URL must be inside the registered web domain that you registred on facebook application.

Comment: Turns out I made a typo when initiating the JS SDK. All's cool now, thanks for the reply.